# Is it possible to display multiple items in the Order Markup using Microdata?

Tags: google-schemas

The documentation at https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/order shows the ability to display multiple items purchased when using the JSON-LD, but there are no examples in case of using MICRODATA.

Is it possible to display multiple items in the markup using MICRODATA?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked closely in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/order) and I think I saw the MICRODATA example beside the JSON-LD tab.

[image]

Comment: Right, thanks, but while the JSON-LD shows examples of multiple products, the MICRODATA does not, hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

There was no answer, I will answer (as I understand it).

```
<div itemprop="acceptedOffer".....
```

Data relating to a particular product in the order are indicated. Total amount, list of products outside this tag.

Now I also have to deal with this issue.